# Extend layout data using controller/block/model

Tags: magento-1.9, module

I want to create a module that changes the title and content of review tab in product page. So far I succeeded to do it using the layout in `/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/me/reviewcontainer.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout version="1.0.0">
    <!-- Product view -->
    <catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="product.reviews">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>my/reviewcontainer/tabs.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="product.info">
            <action method="unsetChild">
                <name>product.reviews</name>
            </action>
            <block type="reviewcontainer/tabs" name="product.reviews" as="reviews"
                   template="my/reviewcontainer/tabs.phtml" after="additional">
                <action method="addToParentGroup">
                    <group>detailed_info</group>
                </action>
                <action method="setTitle" translate="value">
                    <value>Reviews (xxx)</value>
                </action>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

My `etc/config.xml` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <my_ReviewContainer>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </my_ReviewContainer>
    </modules>    
    <!-- we are making changes to the frontend -->
    <frontend>    
        <!-- we are making changes to the layout -->
        <layout>    
            <!-- we are adding a new update file -->
            <updates>    
                <!--
                    this child node name must be
                    unique throughout Magento
                -->
                <my_ReviewContainer>    
                    <!-- the name of the layout file we are adding -->
                    <file>my/reviewcontainer.xml</file>
                </my_ReviewContainer>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

The template is in `/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/my/reviewcontainer/tabs.phtml` and has basic HTML.

Is it possible to change the `Reviews (xxx)` to be dynamically generated by a controller/model/block? If so, what files should I create and where should i put them (being newbie in Magento).

Second, is it possible for me to call some functions in this new controller from withing the tab template? (instead of writing HTML there).

Comment: I have answer for your 1st question. But 'm not clear about your requirement in second question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do two things.

**Step 1 :**

Define `<helpers>` in your `config.xml`.

```
<config>
   ...
    <global>
       <helpers>
           <yourhelper>
             <class>Namespace_Module_Helper</class>
           </yourhelper>
       </helpers>
    </global>
   ...
</config>
```

Then create new file helper in
`app/code/{local|community}/Namespace/Yourmodule/Helper/Data.php`

```
<?php

class Namespace_Your module_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract {
     public function yourfunction(){
       //your logic
      }
}
```

**Step 2:**

Change your layout file as

```
<action method="setTitle" translate="value">
      <value helper="yourhelper/data/yourfunction"/>
</action>
```

So in this the value will get from your helper. In this way you can use your php login the layout file.